# Understanding below python code of creating a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im a noob trying to make sense of this below python code, the `response` variable is something i get from another function, which is ok, but i just cant understand what is this doing `pod_labels_json = [i['spec']['podSelector']` in the below code.

```
response = {'apiVersion': 'example.com/v1', 'items': [{'apiVersion': 'example.com/v1', 'kind': 'ConfigMonitor', 'metadata': {'annotations': {'kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration': '{"apiVersion":"example.com/v1","kind":"ConfigMonitor","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"flakapp-config-monitor","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"configmap":"flaskapp-config","podSelector":{"app":"frontend"}}}\n'}, 'creationTimestamp': '2021-03-30T17:19:53Z', 'generation': 1, 'managedFields': [{'apiVersion': 'example.com/v1', 'fieldsType': 'FieldsV1', 'fieldsV1': {'f:metadata': {'f:annotations': {'.': {}, 'f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration': {}}}, 'f:spec': {'.': {}, 'f:configmap': {}, 'f:podSelector': {'.': {}, 'f:app': {}}}}, 'manager': 'kubectl-client-side-apply', 'operation': 'Update', 'time': '2021-03-30T17:19:53Z'}], 'name': 'flakapp-config-monitor', 'namespace': 'default', 'resourceVersion': '1712971', 'selfLink': '/apis/example.com/v1/namespaces/default/configmonitors/flakapp-config-monitor', 'uid': '4c5c51de-c63f-470a-b79a-f031f2d60bcc'}, 'spec': {'configmap': 'flaskapp-config', 'podSelector': {'app': 'frontend'}}}], 'kind': 'ConfigMonitorList', 'metadata': {'continue': '', 'resourceVersion': '1745397', 'selfLink': '/apis/example.com/v1/configmonitors'}}

pod_labels_json = [i['spec']['podSelector']
                       for i in response['items'] if i['spec']['configmap'] == "flaskapp-config"]
```

Comment: it seems to access a dictionary inside a dictionary

Comment: Which part of that are you asking about? The title suggest the ``for i in ...`` part, the body the ``[i[...][...]`` part. Are you aware of "list comprehension"s? Did you do the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what this is doing is it's looping through the list that you have at `response['items']`. Looks like it's a list of dictionaries. For each dictionary in that list (notated by i), it checks to see if `i['spec']['configmap'] == "flaskapp-config"`. If it is, a new list is being created with the entry being populated as `i['spec']['podSelector']`. What will be returned is a list of those pod selectors based on what fit the criteria. If nothing fits, you will get an empty list.

It's a bit of a short hand for a new list, iterating through the old list, and appending to the new list based on the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

There's a reason they call them "list comprehensions" and not "human comprehensibles". It might help you to understand what's going on if I rewrite the list comprehension as a simple for loop.

```
pod_labels_json = []
for i in response['items']:
   if i['spec']['configmap'] == "flaskapp-config":
        pod_labels_json.append(i['spec']['podSelector'])
```